Why can't I get an output on the printf statement in C language right after the scan statement, the run command skips it completely
I am new to C language coding, I was trying to learn the various inputs that I can take from the user and display the same but I keep getting a blank in the place of the printf statement that takes the value from the previous scanf statement and displays it ( gender part )
please find the screenshot attached of the terminal window and the code below in VS Code.
Thank you
P.S : This is my first ever Stackoverflow post so go easy on me. And I am a complete beginner.
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    printf("\n\nHello my name is Saikat Das");
    printf("Hope you are doing well...\n");
    printf("Its been nice meeting you, see you around\n\n\n");
    
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("\nYour number is : %d\n\n", num);

    float nu;
    printf("Enter a decimal number : ");
    scanf("%f", &nu);
    printf("\nYour number is : %f\n\n", nu);

    char gender;
    printf("\n\nEnter your gender M/F : ");
    scanf("%c", &gender);
       getchar();
    printf("\n\nYour gender is : %c\n\n", gender);

}

enter image description here
I was trying to take a scanf input of a gender from the user ( learning about character scanf input ) and display the same with a printf statement in the next line.

scanf(" %c", &gender); notice the space before %c ... better yet (because scanf() was not designed for user input) use fgets().

The link at the top of the question is incorrect; please see similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/509868
